# How to share memory in unity running on android?

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

I've written an usb driver for a device which updates x,y,z position 200 times a second, I prefer not to call some function to get the new values 200 times a second and thus update the values on a shared memory location.
Is it possible to pass an IntPtr to AndroidJavaObject.call method and use that to access the shared memory or the other way around? 
Or is there a different way to approach this?
There is no point in posting my code because there is none regarding the shared memory.

On unity C# side:

```
        AndroidJavaClass unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");


        float[] res = new float[7];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(res.Length * sizeof(float));

        var ajc = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.t265lib.USBController", unityContext, 256, ptr, null);
```

On Java's side it's just a constructor:

```
    public USBController(Context context, int chunkSize, int ptr,TextView deb) {
        if (deb != null) debugging = deb;
        if (chunkSize != 0) CHUNK_SIZE = chunkSize;
        msg = new byte[9];
        msgResponse = new byte[8];
        resPtr = new float[7];
        this.context = context;
        usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    }
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can save your position inside the Android-Plugin into a variable. Then poll it from Unity as you wish (e.g. inside the Update loop).

#### Android

```
// inner class for position values
public class PositionData {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}

// access data from unity
public PositionData getCurrentPosition() { 
    // TODO: make thread-safe
    return mCurrentPosition;
}
```

#### Unity

```
// class for position values
public class PositionData
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}

// poll position from Android (usbController is initialised somewhere else)
public PositionData ReadPositionData()
{
    var data = usbController.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getCurrentPosition");

    if (data == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Could not retrieve data from Android.");
        return null;
    }

    var positionData = new PositionData
    {
        X = data.Get<int>("x"),
        Y = data.Get<int>("y"),
        Z = data.Get<int>("z")
    };

    return positionData;
}
```

The USB-Communication should be in its own thread and access to its value must be thread safe (Unity runs on the main-thread).

Also you can implement some filtering in Android to smoothen your values.